# How to check a React child component completely rendered including AJAX call inside it?

Tags: reactjs

Is there any mechanism to determine completion of child component rendering, which is having Ajax call in it from parent component.

For below example, i am collection some IDs inside User component with Ajax call. On completion of all User calls i need to fire another AJAX call to get info by collected IDs from earlier request.

```
    {

           Users.map((user,i)=>{
                return <User key={i} user={user} /> //has a ajax call.
           });


           //Do something with collected IDs.
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

React has unidirectional data flow where children listen to changes from parent. If you need the reverse to happen, you need to provide a method which can be called from `User` once its load completes :

```
Users.map((user,i)=>{
    return <User key={i} user={user} onLoad={handleLoad} /> //has a ajax call.
});
```

Like this you can track the load status of each `User`, but this is considered anti-pattern as multiple components are handling the same operation and separation of concern goes for a toss.

Instead make the required fetch in your main component itself, and provide the data to `User` making it completely pure component.

Comment: Thanks @Easwar gaaru. I have a same thought to fire a function from User at last iteration.

Comment: That would still be difficult as you would not know the order in which each `User` component finishes loading. Hence you might need to listen for every component's `onLoad` and proceed only once all have completed. Better pattern would be to go with the second approach.

Comment: It is true, i outseen it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use promises coupled with an event handler as a prop

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that the ajax call should not be in the child component.
The parent already has an array of users. So it could easily make the call.
That would vastly reduce the complexity of your problem.

Is there any good reason why the child needs to make the call?

Here is your other option:
You need to debounce the 'final' ajax call. AND keep a record of all the existing data with a callBack and some local state;
Here is a sandbox solving your problem with the latest and greatest hooks.
https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-hellman-mhc22

Answer (score 0):

You can load the data in a data loader component, and then create the component with the data prop